# Same/different DTO object in create, update and get rest end points?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, dto, content-negotiation

Consider following UserDTO class and UserController exposing endpoints to create, update and get User.

Having the id property in the UserDTO class does not make sense for create and update. If I use swagger or another auto generated API documentation then it shows that the id can be passed in create end point. But the system does not use it as ids are generated internally.

If I look at get then probably I can get rid of the id property but it is certainly required in a list user end point.

I was thinking of returning internal User domain object in get/list end points. This way I can then get rid of id property form UserDTO class.

Is there any better option I can employ for this?

```
public class UserDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody UserDTO user) {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> get(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Void> update(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody UserDTO user) {
    }
}
```

This question may have been asked but I could not find. So excuse me for duplicate question.

Answer (score 13):

[**D**ata **T**ransfer **O**bject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (DTO) is a pattern that was created with a very well defined purpose: **transfer data to remote interfaces**, just like *web services*. This pattern fits very well in REST APIs and DTOs will give you more *flexibility* in the long run.

I would recommend using tailored classes for your endpoints, once REST resource representations don't need to have the same attributes as the persistence objects.

To avoid boilerplate code, you can use mapping frameworks such as [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) to map your REST API DTOs from/to your persistence objects.

For details on the benefits of using DTOs in REST APIs, check the following answers:

- [Why you should use DTOs in your REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227)
- [Using tailored classes of request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387553/1426227)

To give your DTOs better names, check the following answer:

- [Giving meaningful names to your DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35341664/1426227)

Comment: still does not answer the question "how to handle the id for the post request dto". should we have different dtos for get and post actions ?

Answer (score 2):

What's about creating two different interfaces :

```
interface UserDTO {

    public String getName ();

    public void setName (String name);

}

interface IdentifiableUserDTO extends UserDTO {

    public Long getId ();

    public void setId (Long id);

}


class DefaultUserDTO implements IdentifiableUserDTO {

}
```

and then use the Interface in your controller instead of the DTO class :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody IdentifiableUserDTO user) {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> get(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Void> update(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody UserDTO user) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Wael yes that is one of the option. But I just mentioned one such property. There are many more like createdBy, createdTime, updatedBy, updatedTime, etc which are required in the get but does not make sense for create/update. May be use this pattern and instead of calling IdentifiableUserDTO call something else, not sure what would be appropriate.