# How to transport data via REST but not perist them to JPA datasource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a REST API with Spring and `@RestController` and an entity with a JPA repository. Is there a way to transport data (fields) via REST but not persist the corresponding data to the database?

I tried to use `@Transient` for the specific field, which works for persistence but not for transport. The data will not be marshalled/unmarshalled and thus omitted during transport.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you intention. `@Transient` says to JPA not to persist fields being annotated. But at the same time you will be able to pass its' values from frontend to controllers

Comment: I'd like to transport temporary (and dependent) data (which can be regenerated) from client to server without additional objects or entities, but not persist them to the database.

Comment: well, why do you think the `@Transient` data will be lost while mashalling/unmarshalling? or maybe I don't understand you that clear

Comment: Because I tried it and the data is null or let's say not set. :-)

Comment: hm, but I believe it's the problem somewhere else. could you paste your controller, frontend js code related if exists, mvc configuration?

Comment: What does your class look like where you use `@Transient`?

Comment: Problem solved! After some very hard debugging sessions I figured out, that there are different voters for visibility to include the fields to JSON, and if there are normal getter/setter present, the field will be included. And the problem was, I fogot to generate the getter/setter and accidently used another method to set the fields. Bad idead! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest separate representations. A *XxxResource* representation used at the `Controller` level for (de-)serializing via the REST API. And a second *XxxData* or *XxxEntity* representation for JPA/persistence.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm. Let's do an example. We have persons and and list of clothes. I'd like to transport the information about clothes List<Clothes> to the server, but the person should be persisted "naked". Oh my dear, it's only an example :-) Do you suggest to use two different Person entities? But how to transform without to much boilerplate code?

Comment: I assume your REST API accepts a JSON/XML document representing the Person and their Clothes. There would be a `PersonResource` class, containing a `List` of `ClothesResource` class. The incoming document would be deserialized into this Resource representation. If you just want to persist the "person", sans "clothes", then there would be a `PersonEntity` that did not know anything about clothes. You'd convert the `PersonResource` to the `PersonEntity` and persist it. To reduce boilerplate, look at Project Lombok.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest to use two different "entities" for person without inheritance or something. That should work of course, but I'd like to avoid duplicate data and thus code. BTW, Project Lombok is doing the magic for copying the data?

Comment: Not two diferent entities, I'd say what Jamie is suggesting is to have a DTO layer, that is a valid pattern, you have your objects for transfer data, and then, at the controller layer, before going to service, you convert them to business / entities objects. http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174516/rest-api-dtos-or-not , https://medium.com/@schneidenbach/restful-api-best-practices-and-common-pitfalls-7a83ba3763b5

Comment: I know the concept of DTOs and used it a lot, but didn't really like the duplication. But I will have a look at the suggested mapping frameworks. Thank you very much!