# Rename fields in object with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have the JSON:

```
{"400" : "120Hz"}
```

(actually, my JSON is a lot more complex, and, basically, huge)

I use `Jackson` to map data to the `FrequencyDTO`.

```
public class FrequencyDTO {

    @JsonProperty("400")
    private String frequency;

    public String getFreqiency() {
        return this.frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(String frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }
}
```

After that, I need to send this DTO to front end, but I want it's fields to be human-readable, such as: `{"frequency_value" : "120Hz"}`.

The only thing that came to my mind is to create some kind of `FrequencyFrontendDTO`, e.g.:

```
public class FrequencyFrontendDTO {

    @JsonProperty("frequency_value")
    public String frequency;

    //getters and setters
}
```

and map it with `FrequencyDTO`.

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise you to use DTOs. See why in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227).

---

Alternatively you could use [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html). From Jackson 2.9, you could use [`@JsonAlias`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html), which works only for deserialization.

Answer (score 7):

@JsonAlias deserialization all alias in the attribute. But serialization is only for given @JsonProperty

```
public FrequencyDTO() {

@JsonProperty("frequency_value")
@JsonAlias({"400"})
private String frequency;

public String getFreqiency() {
    return this.frequency;
}

public void setFrequency(String frequency) {
    this.frequency = frequency;
}
```

}