# Best Practices for incoming and outgoing DTOs

Tags: java, rest, api-design

I'm facing an API design issue. Consider the following flow:

[image: flow]

As you can see, I have 2 classes to represent my model (`SomethingDTO` and `SomethingResponse`) and 2 classes to represent the 3rd party model (`3rdPartyRequest` and `3rdPartyResponse`).  I'm using a mapper to provide translation from the 3rdPArty model classes to my model classes.

The problem is: all these 4 classes have exactly the same attributes.

Should I repeat these attributes through all these classes? Should I have only one DTO class for the whole flow?

What is the best practice (or pattern) to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I [previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227), using DTOs helps to **decouple** the persistence models from the API models. So you seem to be doing the right thing.

> The problem is: all these 4 classes have exactly the same attributes.

It's always a good idea to decouple the models of your API from the models of a third party API. If the third party API changes *their* contract, you won't break *your* clients. So use different models for each API.

And stick to [mapping frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432956/1426227), such as [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/), to reduce the boilerplate code. You also may want to consider [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to generate getters, setters, `equals()`, `hashcode()` and `toString()` methods for you.

> Should I repeat these attributes through all these classes? Should I have only one DTO class for the whole flow?

If both request and response models contain the *same set of fields*, then you could start with a *single class* for representing both request and response payloads of *each* API. When the fields start to differ (request payload different from the response payload), then you create new models for representing each payload.

In the long run, using distinct models for the request and response will give you flexibility, ensuring you'll expose and receive only the attributes you want to.

Comment: I've tried to edit my comment here in this thread but stackoverflow ask me to wait some minutes do edit.. and I forgot to come back and save the edit. But the comment is almost the same I sent to Augusto ;)
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is a tough one. Being pragmatic Vs correctness.

The correct approach (in my view) is to have a different class for each request/response, which is what you've done. This is because I try to design applications using a [Ports and Adapters architecture](http://wiki.c2.com/?PortsAndAdaptersArchitecture) and also use Domain-Driven Design. The benefit is that this gives more flexibility and clarity in the scenario where the objects start diverging.

If the classes have the exact same attributes, I would take a pragmatic approach of having one class per layer. So one for your Web request/response and one for the 3rd Party. But in no case 'I' would mix 2 integration layers (front end and the 3rd party).

Having single class for the whole thing smells really bad. As I mentioned above, because that is mixing layers (or Ports).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I didn't know about MapStruct. Nice lib. Lombok is not appreciate through my co-workers so we decided avoid it =/ 
I'll merge your advices with @cassiomolin 's advice: start with 1 class per layer and create new ones when the fields start to differ.

Thank you a lot.