# Designing endpoint for performing partial updates with PATCH

Tags: rest, http

Consider a big entity named `entity`. It exposes 100 different updates operations including add and remove properties, update properties, etc.

What should be prefered between using a single URI and many cases handled by application server route:

```
PATCH /entity/[id]  {"type":"a","key1":"val1","key2":"val2"} or
                    {"type":"b","key3":"val3","key4":"val4"} or ...
```

... and using many URIs, one case handled by each application server route:

```
PATCH /entity/[id]/a  {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
PATCH /entity/[id]/b  {"key3":"val3","key4":"val4"}
```

Or maybe using `PUT`? The need is to update (very) partially the entity.

What would be the best approach taking into consideration on REST compliance, load balancers, caching, KISS, etc. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

You should be fine with a single endpoint supporting `PATCH`, as long as you do it right.

The `PATCH` request payload is expected to contain a *set of instructions* for modifying the target resource. Suitable formats for representing this set of intructions are [*JSON Patch*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) and [*JSON Merge Patch*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) (and they allow modifications to nested values in your target JSON document).

## Performing modifications to the state of a resource

To perform modifications to a resource, you could either use `PUT` or `PATCH` (or both). The difference between these methods, however, is reflected in the way the server processes the request payload to modify the target resource:

- In a `PUT` request, the payload is a *modified version* of the resource stored on the server. And the client is requesting the stored version to be *replaced* with the new version. So it may not be entirely suitable for *partial* modifications.
- In a `PATCH` request, the request payload contains a *set of instructions* describing how a resource currently stored on the server should be *modified* to produce a new version. It means it's the most suitable approach for performing *partial* modifications to a resource.

To make things clear, I put together some examples below.

### Using `PUT`

Consider, for example, you are creating an API to manage contacts. On the server, you have a resource that can be represented with the following JSON document:

```js
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Appleseed",
  "work": {
    "title": "Engineer",
    "company": "Acme"
  },
  "phones": [
    {
      "phone": "0000000000",
      "type": "mobile"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let’s say that John has been promoted to senior engineer and you want to keep you contact list updated. We could modify this resource using a `PUT` request, as shown below:

```js
PUT /contacts/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Appleseed",
  "work": {
    "title": "Senior Engineer",
    "company": "Acme"
  },
  "phones": [
    {
      "phone": "0000000000",
      "type": "mobile"
    }
  ]
}
```

With `PUT`, the full representation of the new state of the resource must be sent to the server even when you need to modify a single field of a resource, which may not be desirable in some situations.

From the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**4.3.4. PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)
>
> The `PUT` method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload. […]

### Using `PATCH`

The `PATCH` method definition, however, doesn’t enforce any format for the request payload apart from mentioning that the request payload should contain a set of instructions describing how the resource will be modified and that set of instructions is identified by a media type (which defines how the `PATCH` should be applied by the server).

From the [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789):

> [**2. The PATCH Method**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2)
>
> The `PATCH` method requests that a set of changes described in the request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-URI. The set of changes is represented in a format called a “patch document” identified by a media type. […]

Some suitable formats for describing such set of changes are listed below:

#### JSON Patch

It expresses a sequence of operations to be applied to a JSON document. It is defined in the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) and is identified by the `application/json-patch+json` media type.

The JSON Patch document represents an array of objects and each object represents a single operation to be applied to the target JSON document.

The evaluation of a JSON Patch document begins against a target JSON document and the operations are applied sequentially in the order they appear in the array. Each operation in the sequence is applied to the target document and the resulting document becomes the target of the next operation. The evaluation continues until all operations are successfully applied or until an error condition is encountered.

The operation objects must have exactly one [`op`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4) member, whose value indicates the operation to perform:

- [`add`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.1): Adds the value at the target location; if the value exists in the given location, it’s replaced.
- [`remove`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.2): Removes the value at the target location.
- [`replace`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.3): Replaces the value at the target location.
- [`move`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.4): Removes the value at a specified location and adds it to the target location.
- [`copy`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.5): Copies the value at a specified location to the target location.
- [`test`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.6): Tests that a value at the target location is equal to a specified value.

Any other values are considered errors.

Having said that, a request to modify John’s job title could be:

```js
PATCH /contacts/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/work/title", "value": "Senior Engineer" }
]
```

#### JSON Merge Patch

It's a format that describes the changes to be made to a target JSON document using a syntax that closely mimics the document being modified. It is defined in the [RFC 7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) and is identified by the `application/merge-patch+json` media type.

The server processing a JSON Merge Patch document determine the exact set of changes being requested by comparing the content of the provided patch against the current content of the target document:

- If the merge patch contains members that do not appear within the target document, those members are added.
- If the target does contain the member, the value is replaced.
- `null` values in the merge patch indicate that existing values in the target document are to be removed.
- Other values in the target document will remain untouched.

With this, a request to modify John’s job title could be:

```js
PATCH /contacts/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

{
  "work": {
    "title": "Senior Engineer"
  }
}
```

## The bottom line

When it comes to modifying the state of a resource, the usage of `PUT` and `PATCH` ultimately depends on your needs. Choose one, the other or both. But stick to the standards when supporting them:

- If you choose to support `PUT`, the request payload must be a new representation of the resource (so the server will *replace* the state of the resource).
- If you choose to support `PATCH`, use a standard format for the payload, such as JSON Patch or JSON Merge Patch (which contains a set of instructions that tell the server how to *modify* the state of the resource).

There are many libraries around to parse JSON Patch documents, so don't reinvent the wheel. If you think JSON Patch is too complex for your needs, then use JSON Merge Patch. If are confortable with both formats, then nothing stops you from supporting both formats.

And, as both formats allow you to modify nested values in your JSON document, you should be fine with a single endpoint for `PATCH` even when you have to allow modification in the nested values or your resource.

#### Validating the state of your resources

If you are concerned about how to keep things consistent after applying `PATCH` to your resources, I recommend having a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227). In short, you are advised to **decouple** the models that represent your API resources from the models that represent your domain.

So, when handling a `PATCH` request:

1. Fetch the domain model instance you intend to update.
2. Convert the domain model to the correspondent API resource model.
3. Apply the patch to the API resource model.
4. Convert the API resource model with the updates back to the domain model.
5. Validate the state of the domain model:

- If the state is valid, accept the request and persist the changes made to the domain model.
- Otherwise, refuse the request.

You may also want to refer to the [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) for details on [error handling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.2) when processing `PATCH` request.

#### Further reading <sup>(specially if you use Java and Spring)</sup>

In case you use Java and Spring, you may want to have a look this [post](https://cassiomolin.com/using-http-patch-in-spring) from my blog. If you don't use Java or Spring, the considerations around modifying resources with `PUT` or `PATCH`, in the first part of the post, may still interest you (although I nicely summarized the main idea in this answer).

Comment: Another approach to PATCHing from Google API Design Guideline: https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods#update

Comment: Very clear, thanks you. I see that defining "op" in a PATCH request is good, it fit my needs.

Comment: It's very clear but in fact you don't completely answer the question which was: which one between PATCH /entity/123 {...} . VS PATCH /entity/123/path/456 {...} ? Thanks

Comment: @Slim Check the examples provided in my answer. When using `PATCH` with JSON Patch and JSON Merge Patch, you can modify nested values in your JSON document. So you should be fine with the first URI shown in your question.

Comment: OK thanks @cassiomolin. By the way I am not confortable by setting the path in the patch bodies. What do you think about avoid path in the patch requests? The server can contain a list of commands alone aware of domain concern. ("op" in patch bodies may contain a big variety of command names)

Comment: What brings the specific media types from a simple "json" value?

Comment: @Slim I've updated my answer to address your concerns.