# Is HTTP PATCH restricted to modifying only one field at a time?

Tags: rest, http-patch

Does HTTP `PATCH` method restrict updates to only one field at a time? Can I modify more than one field in a `PATCH` request? Can `PATCH` be used for modifying all the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does HTTP `PATCH` method restrict updates to only one field at a time?

No.

> Can I modify more than one field in a `PATCH` request?

Of course.

> Can `PATCH` be used for modifying all the fields?

Yes. But you may consider `PUT` for that purpose. And, depending on your needs, you may consider supporting `PATCH` along with `PUT` in your API.

---

The [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) method definition doesn’t enforce any format for the request payload apart from mentioning that the request payload should contain a **set of instructions describing how the resource will be modified** and that set of instructions is identified by a media type (which defines how the [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) should be applied by the server).

From the [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789):

> [**2. The PATCH Method**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2)
>
> The `PATCH` method requests that a set of changes described in the request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-URI. The set of changes is represented in a format called a “patch document” identified by a media type. […]

Some suitable formats for describing such set of changes are:

- [*JSON Patch*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) (`application/json-patch+json`)
- [*JSON Merge Patch*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) (`application/merge-patch+json`)

I've added more details about each of these formats in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60098169/1426227) along with a comparison with [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4). So I strongly encourage you to have a look.