# Only Post REST api is working , PUT,GET,DELETE api's are not working in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i have created CRUD api with Spring boot.But Only POST api is working fine.
PUT,GET and DELETE api is not working.

**model**

```
package com.example.crudrestapi.model;


import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String gstin;
    private float outstandingBalance;
}
```

**controller**

```
package com.example.crudrestapi.controller;

import com.example.crudrestapi.model.Customer;
import com.example.crudrestapi.repository.CustomerRepo;
import com.example.crudrestapi.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class CrudController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;

    //    Iterable is used for iter multiple objects( to loop through objects)
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public Iterable<Customer> getCustomer() {

        return customerRepo.findAll();
    }


    @PostMapping("/customers")
    public @ResponseBody
    Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        return customerRepo.save(customer);

    }


    @PutMapping("customers/{customerId}")
    public Customer updateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer newCustomer, @PathVariable Long customerId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        return customerRepo.findById(customerId)
                .map(customer -> {
                    customer.setName(newCustomer.getName());
                    customer.setGstin(newCustomer.getGstin());
                    customer.setPhoneNumber(newCustomer.getPhoneNumber());
                    customer.setAddress(newCustomer.getAddress());
                    customer.setOutstandingBalance(newCustomer.getOutstandingBalance());
                    return customerRepo.save(customer);
                })
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException());
    }

    @DeleteMapping("customers/{customerId}")
    public String deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long customerId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        return customerRepo.findById(customerId)
                .map(customer -> {
                    customerRepo.delete(customer);
                    return "Success";
                })
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException());
    }


}
```

**The Response i'm Getting For the api's is **

> {
> "timestamp": "2020-12-26T16:03:32.723+00:00",
> "status": 500,
> "error": "Internal Server Error",
> "message": "",
> "path": "/customers" }

**Error in Console**

```
 org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.crudrestapi.model.Customer
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:705) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1598) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1762) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:356) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.example.crudrestapi.controller.CrudController.getCustomer(CrudController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Can you add @NoArgsConstructor to your Customer Entity and try again?

Comment: i tried that but i got Error::  java: constructor Customer in class com.example.crudrestapi.model.Customer cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,float
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Add both AllArgsConstructor and NoArgsConstructor annotations for Customer Entity

Comment: That or add an actual no-args constructor that initializes ID and outstandingBalance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems already a tip in log: No default constructor for entity.
So you should add a no arg constructor for entity customer, in Lombok, it is  @NoArgsConstructor

Answer (score 1):

When combining both Lombok's [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Data.html) and [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Builder.html) in the same class, you must also use both [`@NoArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/NoArgsConstructor.html) and [`@AllArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/AllArgsConstructor.html):

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't intend to use [any builder capabilities](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder), drop the [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Builder.html) annotation and use only [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Data.html):

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Customer {
    ...
}
```

---

As a side note, I strongly encourage you to decouple the persistence entities from the API models. That is, you should different classes for persistence and API models. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227) you'll may find more details about it.