# Is it bad to create different classes for REST request and response?

Tags: java, rest

I'm working in a Spring Boot project, as my implement at the moment, almost for each API I have *request* and *response* classes.

For example:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/notice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public AddNoticeResponse addNotice(@Valid @RequestBody AddNoticeRequest){
    Notice notice = ... // creating new notice from AddNoticeRequest
    noticeRepository.save(notice);
    AddNoticeResponse response = ... // creating new response instance from Notice
    return response;
}
```

The request and response classes look like:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AddNoticeRequest{
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    private Long timeToLive;
}
```

```java
// Ommiting some annotations for brevity
public class AddNoticeResponse{
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    private Long timeToLive;
    private Date createTime;
    private String creator;
}
```

I have two problems.

- Creating too many classes and naming them some times made me nuts.
- Some request and response have common fields.

For example: There's two kind of `Notice`: `Email` and `Notification`:

```java
public class Email {
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    private String receiver;
}
```

So, should I use an inner class that extends the common class or just put all the fields into one class? Which is better?

```java
public class AddNoticeRequest {

    private String subject;
    private String message;

    class Email extends AddNoticeRequest{
        private String receiver;
    }
}
```

```java
public class AddNoticeRequest{
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    private Long timeToLive;
    private String receiver;
}
```

Then when the client performs a request to add an `Email` notice, will some fields be null?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using tailored DTOs for request and response will give you more flexibility in the long run. Actually, nothing prevents you from using inheritance and inner classes, but I would just avoid it.

I already answered a *similar* question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227), highlighting the benefits of using DTOs over persistence entities in REST APIs. Below you'll find a few benefits of this approach:

- DTOs can be *tailored* to your needs and they are great when exposing only a set of attributes of your persistence entities. You won't need annotations such as [`@XmlTransient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) and [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) to avoid the serialization of some attributes.
- By using DTOs, you will avoid a *hell of annotations* in your persistence entities, that is, your persistence entities won't be bloated with non persistence related annotations;
- You will have *full control* over the attributes you are receiving when creating or updating a resource;
- If you are using [Swagger](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) to document your REST API, you can use [`@ApiModel`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apimodel) and [`@ApiModelProperty`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apimodelproperty) annotations to document your API models without messing your persistence entities;
- You can have different DTOs for each version of your API;
- You'll have more flexibility when mapping relationships;
- Your DTOs can have a list of links for [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS). That's the kind of thing that shouldn't be added to persistence objects.
- You can use mapping frameworks such as [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) to map your REST API DTOs from/to your persistence objects.

Answer (score 1):

Don't subclass the req/resp objects.

Use an auto de/serialiser like Jackson in your frame work to convert message payloads into business object.

However, you will still end up with a large number of business objects.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use **JSON** format instead of creating class and returning its instance every time. But still if you need a class hierarchy you can create a class and put a variable which will store JSON.