# Ignoring a field without modifying the POJO class with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

My POJO class has `@JsonIgnore` on the declaration of a field, not on the getter and setter methods. It is a generated file and I can't change much in it.

How do I ignore that field while writing using `JsonGenerator.Setting`? Using `@JsonIgnore` on getters and setters works. But can't modify the generated POJO class.

Comment: after generating the class set that property to null.

Comment: The values are being set from the db. I just want to ignore those fields using JsonGenerator. i.e I want to ignore them even if they have values.

Comment: Are you trying to generate list of objects or single object?

Comment: Have you tried the approach I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39790836/1426227)? Could you please let me know if it works?

Comment: Do you mean you have 10 variables in class and the data provided may not contain 10 variables. In that case, give @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) on top of the class.

Comment: @HARDI: The data provided contains those variables but I dont want to display it.

Comment: @AnoopLL: Yes that works! But I dont want to remove the values which those variables contain! Just dont want to display it without changing the generated file.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin: It worked but it was not a solution to my problem. Anyways, accepting Anoops answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Configuring Jackson to use only field annotations

Once the annotations are placed on the fields, you can configure `ObjectMapper` to use only the fields annotations, ignoring the annotations of getters and setters methods:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

### Jackson mix-in annotations

It's a great alternative when modifying your POJOs is not an option. You can think of it as a kind of aspect-oriented way of adding more annotations during runtime, to augment statically defined ones.

Define a mix-in annotation interface (class would do as well):

```java
public interface FooMixIn {

    @JsonIgnore
    String getBar();
}
```

Then configure `ObjectMapper` to use the defined interface (or class) as a mix-in for your POJO:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                                        .addMixIn(Foo.class, FooMixIn.class);
```

Here are some usage considerations:

- All annotation sets that Jackson recognizes can be mixed in.
- All kinds of annotations (member method, static method, field, constructor annotations) can be mixed in.
- Only method (and field) name and signature are used for matching annotations: access definitions (`private`, `protected`, ...) and method implementations are ignored.

For more details, check this [page](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html).

Answer (score 0):

Defining those fields as `transients` with avoid them for being serialized
no matter what annotation for json you uses...

Comment: Cant modify the generated class.