# Is it possible to skip field during serialization at object level?

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I want to create an object in such a way that mentioned fields will be skipped during serialization. Is it possible to do with [Jackson](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/overview-summary.html) or in any other way? I must not change anything or add any annotation on my class.

It must not remove setter from class or use `@JsonIgnore`, because I need the field in other places

For example, if my class has two fields, `a` and `b`, I want to create an object `x` in such a way that when `x` is serialized, the serialized data contains only `a`.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708386/want-to-hide-some-fields-of-an-object-that-are-being-mapped-to-json-by-jackson

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring a field without modifying the POJO class with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789935/ignoring-a-field-without-modifying-the-pojo-class-with-jackson)

Comment: Please read the edited version

Comment: sorry guys my question didnt project what i intended to ask, please check the updated question and description, thanks

Comment: What exactly do you think `@JsonIgnore` does?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Read the question carefully. i can not change my class. Also any annotation i add on class affects all objects