# REST output hide fields in XML but not in JSON

Tags: json, xml, jersey, jax-rs

I don't want one of my Java class model field to appear in the output if my accept type is `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` but the same field should appear in `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` as well as `@XmlTransient` but both seems to hide from JSON output also.

Comment: Have you ever considered tailored DTOs for each media type?

Comment: Are you using Jersey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once annotations such as [`@XmlTransient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) are recognized by both JSON and XML providers, you'd better have [tailored DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227) for each media type you support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am using Jersey. I didn't know about tailored DTOs. I will look at it and get back in case I have additional questions.

Comment: @BolimeraHannah The easiest way to achieve what you want is creating a DTO for each media type you are supporting. That is, one DTO for JSON and one DTO for XML.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please point me to some examples on how to create DTOs ?

Comment: @BolimeraHannah Have a look at this [Martin Fowler's article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html). To give your DTOs a better name, refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35341664/1426227).