# Naming DTO and Entity classes

Tags: spring, java-8, naming-conventions

I have two sets of classes in my spring application - DTOs and Entities.

After reading Clean Code by Uncle Bob, I have got hooked on to naming things right more than ever before.

I sat down refactoring one of my Spring projects and I am not sure if adding DTO suffix for DTO classes is the right thing to do. If not, then how do you differentiate between DTO and Entity classes. I do use Service and Repository suffixes for my service classes and repository interfaces.

Merely keeping them under different packages with same names is not helpful esp. when they are to be used in same scope.

Note: Not sure if this is a precise question to be asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: voting to close... this is opinion-based...

Comment: @Eugene This is the first time I tried to close my question and it just registered it as a vote.

Comment: FWIW - I have also been struggling with how to name these objects. I decided to suffix the DB Entities with `Entity` and leave the DTO's / ViewModels as just the name, e.g. `BillyEntity` and `Billy`. I found that provides the best encapsulation, keeping the 'public' models clean.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724774/java-data-transfer-object-naming-convention/35341664 for some interesting discussions related to this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read [Core J2EE Patterns, 2nd Edition](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/TransferObject.htm), it is called **Transfer Object** with all the sample codes having the `TO` suffix.  You can also have a look at Oracle's [Core J2EE Patterns](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/transferobject-139757.html) site.

To sum up: You should use either `DTO` or `TO` as a suffix to any transfer object you use in your business tier.

Comment: this answer is the worst advice you can follow, read [Java Naming Convention Tautologies](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/02/interface-and-class-naming-anti-patterns-java-naming-convention-tautologies/) to understand why!

Comment: I have provided a link to Oracle's official Core J2EE patterns page, and you provided a link to your own blog.